# Group chat on Google+ on Mac

Tags: mac, chat, google-plus

Does anyone know how to start a multiuser chat on Google+ on Mac OS? It seems like I simply don't have the icon to begin it! I've looked around for an answer but they merely list the instructions, rather easy, to get connected with more friends at once, but lacking the button I can't start any multiuser chat.

I am using Google Chrome on Snow Leopard.

Comment: What browser and version? Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

**From the Mac**
From the actual Mac you need to set up the iChat application on your Mac.

**From the Browser**
Start a chat with a single person in your Chat list.

Once you’ve started the chat, click the person icon at the top of the chat window.

In the field labeled "Add people to this chat", enter the names of the contacts you want to add to your group chat.

*Just in case you want to do this*

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=7c73750a4b0315df&hl=en

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I could seem rather stupid but I don't have that icon! I only have the icon of a videocamera and a phone, then space and the 'Actions'...

Comment: @luigi If you associate your Web Apps and Super User (http://superuser.com) accounts you'll regain ownership of the original question so you can comment.

Comment: So did you try iChat or anything else or not?

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi Yes, that is exactly what was needed :) Your question has been reopened. Best to give all details up front otherwise you will have users shooting in the dark.

Comment: I tried iChat, it doesn't work either! It keeps asking password and password altough I tried to access with my google account